# Use same IP for 2 Ethernet Adapters in different Physical networks

Tags: linux, networking, ip, network-interface

We have a Linux Panel with 2 Network Interfaces. On this Panel runs a software wich needs to comunicate to our devices in our network, and needs to be accessible from the customers network.
One Interface is connected to our Machine Network, with fixed Network Addresses (192.168.1.x), where the Panel has always the IP 192.168.1.1 . The other Interface is the connection to the customers network. Because we deliver our machines everywhere, the customers Network has every sort of configuration. So it can happen, that our second Network port is also in a 192.168.1.x network, it also can happen that we should use the same IP 192.168.1.1

Is this configuration possible? How do I configure it in Linux?

Comment: Sounds interesting. What's the question?

Comment: Sorry. changed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that's just not going to work well—not because of the IP being on both interfaces, but because the subnet is.

If your device needs to talk to 192.168.1.2, which interface should it send that traffic on? Maybe that's the customer's device trying to talk to your device, maybe it's your device trying to talk to one of your other devices. The kernel doesn't (without a bunch of complicated routing setup) know.

A few approaches for this:

1. Pick as small a subnet as possible, out of less-frequently-used RFC1918-space. This minimizes the chance of conflict, but can not eliminate it.
2. Make the internal network space configurable, so the customer (or your support people) can change it to something that doesn't conflict.
3. Use [link-local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) instead of RFC1918 space. Both IPv4 and IPv6 have link-local addresses.
4. Apply for public (routable) IP addresses to use for this. You can use the same set of them on all your devices, basically you're using it like RFC1918 space, just you're guaranteed it won't ever conflict. Very hard to do for IPv4 (we've mostly run out), should be much easier if you can use IPv6.
5. If the processes that need to communicate with customer gear are wholly separate from the ones that need to communicate with your other gear, then you can put each interface in its own network namespace (see `ip netns`), then each namespace only sees one of the 192.168.1.0/24 subnets, so there is no conflict. This would be the simplest of the complicated routing setup.

Comment: If I use Network namespaces, isn't it possible to use NAT from the customer interface to the interface1, so for example my customer interface is seen with a different ip my from software?
On the customers network side, I have only incoming connections.

Comment: @JochenKühner yes, you should be able to set up NAT in one network name space before routing it to a virtual interface that carries it in to the other network name space. I've never tried this, but sounds like it'd work. You could even use static NAT to allow both incoming and outgoing connections.

Comment: Is this also possible in any way without Network Namespaces? Because my device seems not to have compiled support for this (if this can be enabled/disabled) (ip add netns aaa throws an exception). Or have I to compile a Kernel?

Comment: @JochenKühner network namespaces are a Y/n when compiling the kernel, I believe. You can probably do it without them if you have the iptables mark target and have policy routing (to pick a different routing table based on the mark).  Unfortunately, I think those are also optional features.